# Download part of an url content to save bandwith

Tags: java, android

I have an huge text file online, I know how to fetch the data in the url... an example would be something like this

```
        URL url = new URL(address);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null;)
                    builder.append(line);
                response = builder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This file get updated every X minutes and a new line is added to the bottom, so the real info is only in the last line/lines... I was wondering if it would be possible to download only that part, to save bandwith.

Edit: I am looking for a "client-side" solution, without modifying server

Thank you very much.

Comment: for this i think you need the server to support this feature, either by a **custom** implementation like passing required line number(s) or byte index to the server,OR using  RANGE header (http) or REST command (ftp) extra configuration could be required for RANGE and REST

Comment: OR you can change server side -if u can- to write append the new line to the main file A, and also write the new line in a separate file B (constant name), and then it's up to you , ex: first time app starts download file A, then every X minute download file B only

Comment: When downloading the entire file, does the response from the server contain the `Accept-Ranges` header?

Comment: Can't modify server and there's no point in looking particular server configuration because i need to do it on various servers... so I guess the answer is no :D I was looking for a client-side magic... thank you! Should I accept as answer the Yazan one?

Comment: There is no answer yet, so there is nothing to accept.  These are all comments to your question.

Comment: You should check out Mike's comment about Accept-Ranges. Are your "various servers" sending this response header ? You don't have to modify them if they already do.